# An iframe is used to display PDF file. Need to disable right click on Iframe and pdf

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, contextmenu, disable

An `iframe` is used to display PDF file. Need to disable right click on `Iframe` and PDF.

Comment: Please supply starting code so that we may assist you in solving programmatic, logic and other such issues.

Comment: I am using this code. 
```<iframe id="fraDisabled" width="100%" height="473" src="uniform.pdf#toolbar=0"></iframe>```

Comment: ``` <iframe id="fraDisabled" width="100%" height="473" src="uniform.pdf#toolbar=0"></iframe>
 </body>
<script>
 noContext = document.getElementById('fraDisabled');

noContext.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>``` Tried this. But Still I can able to see saves on right click context menu

Answer (score 0):

you will need to look into Element: contextmenu event, you will add event listener and you will disable all elemenr.

for the full details about this you could check Mozilla MDN [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event)

Comment: I tried this it works only on html document. it not works on iframe with PDF document.

Comment: @tnkarthick did you already solved this problem. If yes then please share your experience. I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: do you want to not allow the user to save the document?